# Differential equation $xy^3y'=2y^4+x^4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation
$$xy^3y'=2y^4+x^4$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hint:* Introduce the new function $z(x)$ with $y(x)= x z(x)$ to make the ODE separable.

Ater some calculation, you should obtain
$$ \frac{ z^3z'}{1+z^4} = \frac1x.$$

Comment: Ah, got it! Very helpful! Thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Dividing $xy^3$ on both sides, we get 
$$\tag{1}y'=2\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x^3}{y^3}$$
which is homogenous differential equation. We can use the substitution $u=\frac{y}{x}$. Then 
$y=ux$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{du}{dx}+u$. Substituting it into $(1)$, we obtain
$$x\frac{du}{dx}+u=2u+\frac{1}{u^3}$$
or
$$x\frac{du}{dx}=u+\frac{1}{u^3}$$
which can be solved by separation of variables.

Comment: nice way to choose (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Another method is to realise that $y^3y'$ is, up to a constant factor, the derivative of $y^4$. So we obtain:

\begin{align*}
xy^3y' &= 2y^4 + x^4\\
x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y^4}{4}\right) - 2y^4 &= x^4\\
\frac{d}{dx}(y^4) - \frac{8}{x}y^4 &= 4x^3\\
\end{align*}

where, in the last step, we need $x \neq 0$. Now you can solve this by using an integrating factor.